# How to enable Spring Boot Live Dev Tools on IntelliJ 2021.2 to rebuild classes after modifications and deploy changes to server?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

This is a tutorial on how to enable Dev Tools project on IntelliJ 2021.2 and observe the changes in code without having to restart the Tomcat server.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In order to make it work, you need to:

1)Have devtools enable in maven or gradle. In maven it looks like :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
     <scope>runtime</scope><!-- -->
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

2)In IntellijIDEA: go in settings(ctrl +alt+s) -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> compiler, check "Build project automatically"

**3) Enable option 'allow auto-make to start even if developed application is currently running' in Settings -> Advanced Settings under compiler**

[image]

You can now restart your intelliJ IDE and start your application.

Comment: If there is no Advanced Settings section you can try change registry flag from registry. 1- Double shift and search registry. 2- set true the value of  compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running

Answer (score 4):

1.file->settings->Build,Execution,Deployment->compiler->click->Build project automatically->apply->ok

2.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
     <scope>runtime</scope><!-- -->
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

3.file->settings->advance option->allow auto make start even if developed application in currently running->apply->ok

4.restart IDE

Comment: <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
     <scope>runtime</scope><!-- -->
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>

Answer (score 2):

**Set Up your Project and IDE.**

1. Add the POM dependency.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
```

2. In IntellijIDEA: File -> Settings... -> **Build, Execution, Deployment** -> Compiler: Check "Build project automatically"
3. In IntellijIDEA: File -> Settings... -> **Advanced Settings**: Check "Allow auto-make to start even if developed application is currently running"

**Set Up your Browser.**

1. Add the "LiveReload" extension to your browser. Eg: if you are using Chrome Brower add the "LiveReload" extension by livereload.com.
2. Initially when you start your app, load in a browser tab and hover over the 'LiveReload' extension to ensure it is enabled. The tooltip should show as "LiveReload is connected, click to disable Has access to this site".
   [LiveReload Tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jc039.jpg)

Once these are set up, to ensure both Automatic Restart and LiveReload;

1. Do changes to both the Static files and Java files in the application that is already running.
2. Build the project (Build -> '**Build Project**' or Ctrl+F9).
3. Observe the application automatically restarting with "LiveReload server is running on port .. " in the IDE console and the browser is refreshed.

Comment: I see a ClassPathChangedEvent in the logs when I run build, but the changes are still not reflected. For testing, I implemented a simple Spring Scheduler and changed the log message printed every second. And also, do I need to run Build Project whenever I change something? because that's not really any gain compared to restarting the application. Using Quarkus for example, it will apply code changes when the file gets changed automatically