# Springboot - update classes without restarting Tomcat Server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

In my Spring Boot (2.6.4) project I would like to know if it is possible to make changes to a class (for example entity, DTO or controller) and have the changed classes reload without having to restart the whole application ([like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69449905/how-to-enable-spring-boot-live-dev-tools-on-intellij-2021-2-to-rebuild-classes-a))

My environment consists of:
IDE: Intellij Idea 2023 Ultimate
Build Tool: Gradle

I have enabled the options in Intellij for:

- Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Compiler : Build Project Automatically (ticked)
- Enabled option 'allow auto-make to start even if developed application is currently running' in Settings -> Advanced Settings under compiler

In gradle I have tried both options:

```
developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
and
compileOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
```

I am Debugging the project in Intellij using the Green Debug icon on the tool menu.

I then tried to make a change to a Dto class while running the project in Debug, for example:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class CarDto {
    @JsonProperty("carId")
    private Long carId;
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
}
```

By commenting out the two lines:

```
//@JsonProperty("name")
//private String name;
```

But there is no indication on the terminal in Intellij that it has detected the changes and reloaded the changed classes.

**UPDATED**

Another more recent [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71612680/spring-dev-tools-does-not-reloading-changes-in-project-intellij-idea) states that it is controlled by the run configuration in Intellij.

It states:

1. Install Spring Boot Developer tools;
2. Set the `On Update Action` in `Run Configuration` to `Hot swap classes and update trigger file if failed`
3. `On Frame deactivation` have the class `Update Classes and Resources'

[image]

**Q:** How can I get the live reload to work - it appears there is a few different sets of instructions.

I can post more of the `build.gradle` if needed.

Comment: To avoid a server restart on each change you could try to get rid of `spring-boot-devtools` dependency and hotswap changes as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/61416076/12844632 Notice that there are some known hotswap limitations https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/altering-the-program-s-execution-flow.html#limitations

Answer (score 1):

Are you just changing the classes while debugging, or are you you planning to update the  application on a running server.
Intellij has had hot-reload, 10+ years before Spring boot was invented, so I personally don't use `spring-boot-devtools`, just start the application in the debugger and, do shit+F9 (old hotkey) to recompile and reload the classes of the JVM.

Comment: This is all local for development. During development Tomcat is running. I am changing classes - for example DTO as per above.

Comment: I have worked with Intellij since 2003, I don't remember a time where you could not hot reload classes in the debugger :). Just recompile and Intellij will have the JVM reload the changed class files.